# qt5.12 create dialog with winapi

Tags: winapi, qt5

I want to create dialog on windows that will be show on top level (even game window) like task manager. I wrote the next code:

```
    static const wchar_t* className = L"GraphDialog";
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wx.lpszClassName = className;
    if ( RegisterClassEx(&wx) )
    {
        HWND h = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, (LPCWSTR)className, NULL, WS_POPUP,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        QWindow *qw = QWindow::fromWinId((WId)h);
        if (qw)
        {
            GraphDialog* dialog = qobject_cast<GraphDialog*>(createWindowContainer(qw));
            if (dialog)
            {
                dialog->init(...);
                dialog->exec();
            }
        }
    }
```

GraphDialog is QDialog.
Unfortunately I have mistake SIGSEGV when function CreateWindowEx is called.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Answer (score 3):

Your registered class hasn't set the [**lpfnWndProc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexa#members) member which caused *SIGSEGV*.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `NULL` for `lpWindowName`:

```c
HWND h = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, (LPCWSTR)className, NULL /*<------ lpWindowName*/, WS_POPUP,
         CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
         CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
         NULL, NULL, NULL /* <---- hInstance */, NULL);
```

I don't see any indication in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) that this is allowed.  If it were, I'd also expect to see something documented for passing `NULL` to [SetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw), but it is conspicuously absent.

It's also not clear that you're allowed to pass `NULL` in for the `hInstance` parameter.

Pass in some text for `lpWindowName` and have a look at passing in a handle for `hInstance`.